# Synchronizing tables on 2 MySQL servers

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have 2 MySQL servers: one for development, other for production. Both contain same table structure, but different data on tables.

When I have done change on dev server, like add column to table, I have manually made the same change later to production server. But this slow and error prone, especially if there are many changes to be made at once.

Is there better way to do this? I have phpMyAdmin, maybe that has some neat trick?

Also, is there a dedicated term for what this process is called? Searching for 'table update' or similar does not yield results on this topic.

**EDIT:**

Forgot to mention that I am using Windows.

So apparently I need some kind of diff tool for this. I haven't tested all of these proposed software yet, but so far they seem very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Red Gate's SQL Compare before for SQL Server; [this is their MySQL product](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/mysql-compare/). I don't have the budget to buy it myself, but if it works anything like SQL Compare did, it'll do exactly what you want it to do.

Comment: It doesn't cost anything (yet). Bear in mind that you can use this for free while it's still in beta!

Comment: Oh, win, I must have missed that. Thanks!

Comment: I chose this one, but any of these apps could propably have done the job.

Comment: Update: MySQL Compare is now fully released and has a fully functional 14-day trial. http://mysql-compare.com/

Answer (score 1):

When ever I do this I have used the data or structure sync in a Mysql GUI app called Navicat, there is a free version available and it does what you asked perfectley.

Answer (score 1):

Try to compare and synchronize databases with schema/data comparers in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/).