# Diffing and Synchronizing 2 tables MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine, diff

I have 2 tables, One with new data, and another with old data.

I need to find the `diff` between the two tables and push only the changes into the table with the old data as it will be in production.

Both the tables are identical in terms of columns, only the data varies.

**EDIT:**
I am looking for only one way sync

**EDIT 2**
The table may have foreign keys.

Here are the constraints

- I can't use shell utilities like `mk-table-sync`
- I can't use gui tools,because they cannot be automated, like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5567317/492561).
- This needs to be done programmatically, or in the db.
- I am working in `python` on Google App-engine.

Currently I am doing things like

- `OUTER JOIN`s and `WHERE [NOT] EXISTS` to compare each record in `SQL` queries and pushing the results.

My questions are

- Is there a  better way to do this ?
- Is it better to do this in python rather than in the db ?

Comment: Assuming you want only a one-way sync: why don't you just wipe the old table completely and fill all data from the new one? Too much data?

Comment: Yes I want only one way Sync.
As I said before since It will be in production I can't just drop the table and replace it, Yes It may have thousands of rows

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment to my question, you could simply do:

```
DELETE FROM OldTable;

INSERT INTO OldTable (field1, field2, ...) SELECT * FROM NewTable;
```

As I pointed out above, there might be reasons not to do this, e.g., data size.

Comment: This is a bad Idea on a production database with thousands of records, and especially considering that it may have foreign keys.

Comment: O.k. your original reply to my question didn't state this. Thus my solution is not possible.